# Unable to call navigation controller from present view controller in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

In my application i am launching one screen using present `UIModalViewController` and on that screen I have one`UIButton`, if we click on that `UIButton` alert will come then select yes on alert view now we have to call another view using`pushviewcontroller`. But screen is not coming if we use below code can any one help me.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:requestViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: please check that the presented view controller has navigation controller.If not go to storyboard selct the view controller  and add navigation controller, then only the push controller will work'

Comment: Where are you calling this code?

Comment: is this presented view controller embedded in a navigation view controller? then only i think this will work

Answer (score 1):

Try with one root navigation controller and then present your controller modally as follows :

```
FirstViewController *firstView=[[FirstViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]                                               initWithRootViewController:firstView];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and then for push another view as  follow :

```
SecondViewController *secondView=[[SecondViewController alloc]init];     
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
```

It will work first using present modal viewController and then using push navigation viewControllers on to the stack.